Ice candidates is not generated in WebRtc
I am creating a small project for which I require a video call feature. That's why I have used WebRTC, and for signalling I am using my self- created socket.io server. The problem is that my offer and answer were successfully created, but ice candidates are not being generated.
Here is my code.:
const call = document.getElementById("call")
const endcall = document.getElementById("endcall")
const videosection = document.getElementById('rightvideo')
const user1 = document.getElementById('user1') // first video pannel which shows client video
const user2 = document.getElementById('user2') //second video pannel which shows remote videos
const servers = {
    iceServers:[
        {
            urls:['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302','stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302']
        }
    ]
}

const socket = io();
let localstream;
let remotestream;
let poffer;
let peerconnection;
let recieverid = undefined;

let recieversidermoteoffer;
let recieversidelocalanswer;
let sendersideoffer;
let sendersideanswer;

// sender side
socket.on('answer',async (data)=>{
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('answer recieved  sent by ',recieverid,' ',data.ans)
    sendersideanswer = data.ans;
    await peerconnection.setLocalDescription(sendersideoffer);
    if(!peerconnection.currentRemoteDescription)
    await peerconnection.setRemoteDescription(sendersideanswer);
})

//reciever side
socket.on('offer',(data)=>{
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    videosection.style.display = 'flex';
    recieversidermoteoffer = data.offer;
    settingsteam();
    createanswer();
})

//common
socket.on('candidate',async (data)=>{
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    await peerconnection.addIceCandidate(data.icecandidate)
})
call.onclick = ()=>{
    if(recieverid)
    {
        callinit()
        videosection.style.display = 'flex';
    }
}
endcall.onclick = ()=>{
    if(localstream){
    localstream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{
        track.stop()
    })}
    videosection.style.display = 'none';
}


//function area

//sender side
let callinit = async ()=>{
    settingsteam();
    createpeerconnection();
    // creating offer
    poffer = await peerconnection.createOffer()
    sendersideoffer = poffer;
    socket.emit('offer',JSON.stringify({reciever:recieverid,offer:poffer}))
}

//reciever side
let createanswer = async ()=>{
    createpeerconnection();
    await peerconnection.setLocalDescription(recieversidelocalanswer)
    await peerconnection.setRemoteDescription(recieversidermoteoffer);
    let answer = await peerconnection.createAnswer();
    recieversidelocalanswer = answer;
    socket.emit('answer',JSON.stringify({reciever:recieverid,ans:answer}))
}
//common
let settingsteam =async ()=>{
    localstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:false});
    remotestream = new MediaStream();
    user1.srcObject = localstream;
    user2.srcObject = remotestream;
}
let createpeerconnection =async ()=>{
    peerconnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
     peerconnection.onicecandidate = (e)=>{
     if(e.candidate)
     {
       socket.emit('candidate',JSON.stringify({reciever:recieverid,icecandidate:e.candidate}))
     }
    }
    if(!localstream)
    {
        localstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:false});
        user1.srcObject = localstream
    }
    localstream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{
        peerconnection.addTrack(track)
    })

    peerconnection.ontrack = (event)=>{
        event.streams[0].getTracks = (tracks)=>{
            remotestream.addTrack(tracks)
        }
    }


}

With the help of one answer on stack overflow, I tried adding trans-receiver property, and it did work, but ice candidates were only generated on the system, which initiated the call and created the offer.
Here is link from where I added idea of transreciever.
No ICE candidates generated when I run my local webRTC application on google chrome browser

You may try to do 1 of the following things before calling  peerconnection.createOffer()

Call peerconnection.createDataChannel to create a data channel;
Call peerconnection.addTrack to add media track to peerconnection object.

